# Can I get a visa on arrival at Rome airport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, italy

I am traveling back from Argentina to Delhi via Rome. I hold an Indian passport. My wait time in Rome is 10 hours. Can I get a visa on arrival for sightseeing in Rome airport?

Answer (score 5):

Indians need a visa to enter Italy, and Schengen visas are only issued on arrival in emergencies.

So you will need a visa from the Italian embassy.